# Do I lose my buffs after if I die and revive (not respawn)?

Tags: league-of-legends

Let's say I play Anivia, Aatrox or Zac ( or any other champion that revives after death) And I have blue, red and baronbuff.

I then get killed but I don't die immediatly because of the passive. Let's say I don't get killed during the passive and come back alive.

Have I lost the buffs or did I kept the buffs?

Is this the same with Guardian Angel?

Comment: short answer is no

Comment: @ken I actually also can't think of a long answer...

Comment: @AtlasEU The title you edited doesn't emphasise the special case of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You will keep the buffs!**

On-Death effects will only trigger if you actually die. This means if you Don't see a grey screen, you have everything you had before including Buffs, Mejai stacks and Sword of the occult stacks.

**If your death counter doesn't change, you won't lose anything**

Comment: but its a different story if your the gravedigger(i forgot his name) and was ultied

Comment: @ken true but Yoricks ult won't prevent you from dying (your death counter goes up).

Comment: Same with karthus, you don't keep the buffs when you die.

Comment: In short, you won't keep the buffs in the afterlife.